# How do I serve a Github page through a custom domain when the content is stored in the docs folder?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a project site in Github that is served through a custom domain (rented through Google Domains). I first configured the repository to serve directly from the `master` branch, and configured the DNS records in Google accordingly.

Specifically, the `A` record is set to

```
185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153
```

and the `CNAME` record is set to `myusername.github.io`. In the Github repository, I created the `CNAME` file with `mycustomdomain.org` and changed the repository settings to use it. *This works properly*.

However, once I change the Github Pages setting to use the `/docs` folder on the master branch, I can't access the site through `mycustomdomain.org`. (It's a 404 error) Intuitively, it's now at `mycustomdomain.org/docs`. Is there any way to both serve the pages from the `docs` folder **and** access the site through the top-level domain?

Comment: Did you generate the static files through Angular2 or Reactjs build?

Comment: No. They're generated through a Python script I wrote that processes some Jinja templates, but I'm hoping for a solution that's independent of how the static pages were generated.

Comment: Is your project public? I can have a look at this by forking it into my account... Considering what you have done so far, it was supposed to work as expected.

Comment: The project is not public, unfortunately. (Work policy; I realize how silly that is given that GitHub is not on my company's premises)

Comment: Where is your CNAME file? Is it in the root of your repo or in the /docs folder? If it is in the root of the repo, can you please try to move it to the /docs folder?

Comment: @ChunLiu Thank you! I have officially broadcast my ignorance about Github Pages here. It was as simple as moving the CNAME file to the `docs` subfolder. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it and award you the bounty.

Comment: @MichaelA Glad to know it solved the problem. I'll post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving CNAME file from the root of the repo to the `/docs` folder solved the problem.

**Reference**: The `CNAME errors` are mentioned [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-custom-domains-and-github-pages#cname-errors#:%7E:text=Custom%20domains%20are%20stored%20in%20a%20CNAME%20file%20in%20the%20root%20of%20your%20publishing%20source.) in GitHub documents.